# What is meant by "reduced homology eliminates many exceptional cases (as in the homology groups of spheres)"?

Tags: algebraic-topology

As part of trying to understand why reduced homology is useful, I encountered the following statement in Wikipedia's article on reduced homology:

> "...reduced homology eliminates many exceptional cases (as in the homology groups of spheres)."

What exceptional cases of the homology groups of spheres is this referencing? Is there a simple example (I've only started learning about reduced homology recently)?

Comment: Not sure this needs a full answer but compare for $S^n$ what $H_n(S^n)$ and  $\tilde{H}_n(S^n)$ are and then think about $S^0$. Recall, $S^0$ is two points by convention. Similarly with what $H_0$ would have been for $S^0$ vs $S^n$. $n=0$ is pretty much the only exceptional case.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Thanks! I'll have a go and post a response here once I work it out.

Comment: Sounds good :) It's probably easiest to just remember that "calculation wise" reduced homology is essentially the same as regular homology but remove a $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension $0$. This should let you compute all those above examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is not always a good source. It says

> reduced homology eliminates many exceptional cases (as in the homology groups of spheres).

This is a very vague statement and we can only guess what it wants to express. Probably it wants to say that

$$\tilde H_k(S^n) = \begin{cases}\mathbb Z & k = n \\ 0 & k \ne n \end{cases}$$
in contrast to
$$H_k(S^n) = \begin{cases}\mathbb Z & k = 0,n \\ 0 & k \ne 0,n \end{cases}$$

In fact, for each space $X$ we have $\tilde H_k(X) = H_k(X)$ for $k  > 0$ and $\tilde H_0(X) \oplus \mathbb Z \approx H_0(X)$. The summand $\mathbb Z$ is the $0$-th homology group of the one-point space $*$. Usually one regards  the homology groups of $*$ as trivial, and *eliminating* this trivial part gives the reduced homology groups $\tilde H_k(X)$.

Comment: For $S^0$ isn't the second one supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ for $k=n$ (two connected components)? Maybe it's $S^0$ that behaves oddly in the regular homology groups?

Comment: @Anon Nice observation, could be a reason for the Wikipedia statement. Nevertheless the statement is too vague to identify what the author "really" wanted to express.